# Kлик мыши по изображению - Pygame, Python

Tags: python, python-2.7, pygame

У меня имеется код, где есть два слоя - с текстом и с задним фоном. При написании функции для клика мышки появляется, как будто новый слой, который закрывает предыдущие. Какое может быть решение данной проблемы? Вот сам код:

```
    # -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
    import pygame, sys, os
    from pygame import *
    import time
    import codecs

    pygame.init()
    running = True
    screen = pygame.display.set_mode((1110, 500))
    pygame.display.set_caption("GENDER")


    mypath = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__))
    p_path = os.path.join(mypath,'yeah.png')
    player_image = pygame.sprite.Sprite()
    player_image.image = pygame.image.load(p_path).convert()
    player_image.rect = player_image.image.get_rect().move(0, 0)

    font = pygame.font.Font('GOTHA.OTF', 14)
    font_color = (47, 79, 79)
    font_background = (255, 255, 255)
    t = font.render('tweet1', True, font_color, font_background)
    t_rect = t.get_rect()
    t_rect.centerx, t_rect.centery = 560, 100

    font = pygame.font.Font('GOTHA.OTF', 25)
    font_color2 = (0, 0, 0)
    font_background2 = (255, 255, 255)
    t2 = font.render('res', True, font_color2, font_background2)
    t2_rect = t2.get_rect()
    t2_rect.centerx, t2_rect.centery = 300, 350

    x = 1100
    y = 500

    running = True
    while (running):
        for event in pygame.event.get ():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                running = False
            if event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
                x, y = event.pos
                if player_image.image.get_rect ().collidepoint (x, y):
                    print 'tweet'

   def update():
        screen.blit(player_image.image, player_image.rect)
        screen.blit(t, t_rect)
        screen.blit(t2, t2_rect)


  if __name__ == "__main__":
      while running:
        update()
        pygame.display.flip()
        clock.tick(30)
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                sys.exit()
```

Comment: в какой момент вы думаете `if __name__ == "__main__":` код выполняется?

Comment: если вы так написали, думаю нигде. 
я вставила цикл с кнопкой после while running

Comment: он он всё равно как будто не видит кнопку и действия не происходит

Comment: решайте одну проблему за раз. Сейчас у вас проблема: вы не знаете когда код верхнего уровня выполняется (основы). Начните с использования одного цикла.